# Uniqueness proof of binary representation

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

I'm having trouble understanding this proof of uniqueness of binary representation of integers:

> Suppose there exists an integer $n$ with two different binary representations. Let these be:
>
> $$2^r + c_{r-1}\cdot2^{r-1} + \cdots + c_1 \cdot 2 + c_0 =  2^s + d_{s-1}\cdot2^{s-1} + \cdots + d_1 \cdot 2 + d_0$$ where $c_i, d_i$ are either $1$ or $0$.
>
> Without loss of generality, assume that $r<s$.
>
> Now, $2^r + c_{r-1}\cdot2^{r-1} + \cdots + c_1 \cdot 2 + c_0 \leq 2^r + 2^{r-1} + \cdots + 2 + 1$
>
> = $2^{r+1}-1$ (summing the geometric series)

Now the book throws the bouncer:

> $<2^s$

And then goes on to show that the first number is less than the second, which is a contradiction. I'm stumped as to how $2^{r+1} - 1 < 2^s$, when we have no definite information about $r$ and $s$. For all we know, maybe $s$ is less than twice of $r$.

Please help.

Comment: When $s>r$ then $s\geq r+1$ and therefore $2^s\geq 2^{r+1}>2^{r+1}-1$.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter Excellent! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

More generally, we can show uniqueness with respect to any basis $b>1$ (integer).

Suppose $n=x_0+x_1b+x_2b^2+\dots+x_rb^r=y_0+y_1b+y_2b^2+\dots+y_sb^s$, where $0\le x_i<b$ and $0\le y_j<b$, but $x_r\ne0$ and $y_s\ne0$.

First of all, we must have $r=s$. Otherwise, suppose $r>s$; then
$$
x_0+x_1b+x_2b^2+\dots+x_rb^r\ge x_rb^r\ge b^{r}
$$
and
$$
y_0+y_1b+y_2b^2+\dots+y_sb^s<b^{s+1}\le b^r,
$$
a contradiction. Why $y_0+y_1b+y_2b^2+\dots+y_sb^s<b^{s+1}$? Prove it by induction.

So $r=s$. Consequently, $x_0=y_0$, because this is the remainder of the division of $n$ by $b$. The conclusion follows by induction, because we have
$$
b(x_1+x_2b+\dots+x_rb^{r-1})=b(y_1+y_2b+\dots+y_rb^{r-1})
$$

Comment: Very nicely explained! Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: "$x_0+x_1b+x_2b^2+\dots+x_rb^r\ge x_rb^r\ge b^{r}$ and $y_0+y_1b+y_2b^2+\dots+y_sb^s<b^{s+1}\le b^r$, a contradiction". I disagree that this is a contradiction since your loose bounds allow for both equal to $b^r$, which avoids the claimed contradiction.  Better (in my opinion) for the second series to write: $y_0+y_1b+y_2b^2+\dots+y_sb^s\le b^{s+1}-1\le b^r-1<b^r$, and that is a definite contradiction since the same sum cannot be greater than or equal to *and* less than, a given value at the same time.

Comment: @Deepak In the second one there is a *strict* inequality: so $y_0+y_1b+\dots+y_sb^s<b^r$.

Comment: @egreg Not the way you wrote it in the answer.

Comment: @Deepak Sorry, I don't understand. If you put together the two displayed parts you get $y_0+\dots+y_sb^s<b^{s+1}\le b^r\le x_0+\dots+x_rb^r$, which contradicts the two extremes being equal.

Comment: I guess I had a problem with the presentation more than anything else. The problem is the ambiguity of transitivity when dealing with a chain of strict & mixed inequalities. When you say $a = b = c$, that's unequivocal, and when you say $a<b<c$, that's also unequivocal since you can conclude $a<c$. However, if you write $a<b\le c$, for some reason, my brain "glitches" on the transitive step to conclude $a<c$. Probably more a niggling semantic objection more than anything, but for what it's worth, I wouldn't write it as you did. If no one else has an issue with understanding it, then it's fine.

Comment: @Deepak Let's keep the comments, then.

Comment: Sure, thank you.

Comment: Proof that $y_0+y_1b+y_2b^2+\dots+y_sb^s<b^{s+1}$ without induction: 
Since all $y_i <b$, we have  $$y_0+y_1b+y_2b^2+\dots+y_s b^s \le (b-1)\left(\dfrac{b^{s+1}-1}{b-1}\right)=b^{s+1}-1 <b^{s+1}$$