# Determining the values a random variable takes

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $(X_n)$ be IID bernoulli random variables and set $$Y_n = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{X_i}{2^i}$$

I am trying to show this converges weakly to the uniform distribution on $[0,1]$. I am given a hint that I should first show what values it takes, and find it's distrubtion function. I found solutions online which state $Y_n$ takes values $k/2^n$ for $0 \leq k \leq 2^n - 1$ each with probability $1/2^n$ - I can't see this. Could someone please explain why this is so

Comment: If $\mathbb{P}(X_i = 0) = \mathbb{P}(X_i = 1) = 1/2$ for $i \in \{1,\ldots,n\}$, then for any $0 \leq k \leq 2^n-1$
$$\mathbb{P}\left(Y = \frac{k}{2^n}\right) = \frac{1}{2^n}.$$
Intuitively this is clear since $X_i$ solely takes values in $\{0,1\}$. Suppose there are $0 \leq m \leq n$ of the $X_i's$ that are equal to zero and the reaming $n-m$ are equal to one. The corresponding value for $Y_n$ has probability (because of independence)
$$\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^m \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n-m} = \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n.$$
This is true for any arbitrary $m \in \{0,\ldots,m\}$.

Comment: @Siron thanks, but I don't understand how they got that $Y = \frac{k}{2^n}$ for $0 \leq k \leq 2^n-1$ from? Where did this range of $k$ come from, and why is $Y = \frac{k}{2^n}$

Answer (score 3):

Actually the sequence $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n$ can be thought as the digits of $Y$ in binary representation: 
$$0.X_1X_2\ldots X_n$$

So it is ranging from $0.00\ldots0$ to $0.11\ldots1$ with equal probability.

The uniqueness of the representation can be seen, e.g.
[Uniqueness proof of binary representation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/607674/uniqueness-proof-of-binary-representation)

Comment: thanks, but I don't understand how they got that $Y = \frac{k}{2^n}$ for $0 \leq k \leq 2^n-1$ from? Where did this range of $k$ come from, and why is $Y = \frac{k}{2^n}$