# Why can WLOG be used in binary integer representation theorem?

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics

I was trying to understand the uniqueness portion of the proof for integer representation theorem.

Then I saw this:https://math.stackexchange.com/a/607774/789305.

He made an assumption that $r>s$, reached a contradiction and then claimed $r$ is not $>$ $s$.

He immediately then claims $r=s$.

---

This was the same case with the book I was using to read:

[image]

---

Shouldn't they also cover the "Assume the $r<s$" part, repeat the same steps on reaching a contradiction and only then claim $r=s$?

Edited:
I understand that the part WLOG(without loss of generality) means that validity of proof is applicable in general despite narrowing the statement to a particular case(due to assumption). This means that I don't have to add the "Assume the $r<s$" part

But the question is why is  $r>s$ of WLOG. What makes that so obvious?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $r\ne s$. Then without loss of generality one can assume that $r<s$. This is perfectly fine.

If $r>s$, then one could swap the numbers such that $r<s$ without loss of generality.
So there is no need to handle the case $r>s$ separately.

Comment: I'll rephrase my question then. It seems I don't understand why  assumption of r<s is WLOG

Comment: @Leon due to the second paragraph: the proof would be exactly the same if r<s.

Comment: @Student Ahh so we can type in WLOG as long as the steps are going to be extremely similar that it's obvious?

Comment: @Leon yes, you can always assume on of both will be the smallest one. If it were the other one, the proof will be the same.

Comment: @Student what do you mean by "`on of both will be the smallest one`."?

Comment: @Leon picking two numbers r, s then either r=s (which you assume is not the case in this proof by contradiction) or r<s or r>s (hence one of two is the smallest one)